# How do I catch and rethrow an error in Perl?

Tags: perl

Let's say I have a module Bar that is a subclass wrapper for module Foo.  I want calls to Bar's methods to mimic Foo's exactly -- even down to fatal errors.  So far, easy enough; I just call the SUPER method.

```
sub stuff {
    # Do stuff here

    SUPER::stuff(@_);

    # Do more stuff here
}
```

But, let's say that I want to catch, log, and rethrow any fatal errors `SUPER::stuff()` produces.  First two steps are easy:

```
sub stuff {
    # Do stuff here

    eval {
        SUPER::stuff(@_);
    };
    $@ and log("Naughty, naughty: $@");

    # Do more stuff here
}
```

... but I don't know how to do the last part.  How do I re-throw the error in such a way that the caller will be unable to distinguish between a call to `Foo->stuff()` and a call to `Bar->stuff()`?  Can I just insert `die $@` after the log statement and expect it to do what I want, or are there nuances here that would likely get me into trouble?

Comment: Avoid using checking `$@` after `eval`, especially with OO code. See [`Try::Tiny`](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.09/lib/Try/Tiny.pm#BACKGROUND)

Comment: @tchrist, I agree, but I have also seen the `$@` gets reset after an `eval` bug crop up in production code.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: Do you feel that the 5.14 fixes to `$@` treatment address this?

Comment: @tchrist, It looks like it will.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: I'm **VERY** glad to hear that. I would much rather fix problems than forever work around them.

Answer (score 6):

The full code to safely eval/catch/log/rethrow in Perl can be a bit verbose.

```
sub stuff {
    # Do stuff here

    local $@; # don't reset $@ for our caller.
    my $eval_ok = eval { # get the return from eval, it will be undef if the eval catches an error.
        SUPER::stuff(@_);
        1; # return 1 (true) if there are no errors caught.
    };
    if (!$eval_ok) { # don't trust $@ it might have been reset as the eval unrolled.
        my $error = $@ || 'unknown error'; # copy $@ incase write_log resets $@, or is later changed to cause it to reset $@.
        write_log("Naughty, naughty: $error");
        die $error; # after all that we can rethrow our error.
    }

    # Do more stuff here
}
```

You can use [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny) sugested by mob to simplify:

```
sub stuff {
    # Do stuff here

    try {
        SUPER::stuff(@_);
    } catch {
        my $error = $_;
        write_log("Naughty, naughty: $error");
        die $error;
    }

    # Do more stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're proposing will work. Perl doesn't have structured exceptions so the data in `$@` is all the caller would get anyway.

Comment: But `$@` *can* hold an object, which *can* give you structured exceptions.

Comment: @tchrist:  But if I just re-die with `$@` as my argument, am I losing any data?  (Assuming I store `$@` to another var so it doesn't get overwritten by something else, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

```
 eval {
        SUPER::stuff(@_);
    };
    $@ and ( log("Naughty, naughty: $@"), die $@ );
```

Comment: You example calls `log` and then calls `die`, due to the global nature of `$@` you can't trust that `log` won't change or reset the value in `$@` before it's passed to `die`.